# High Frequency Data Listener TCP Overload on WIndows 7

Tags: windows, sockets, networking, tcp

I have coded a c# based listener to retrieve data from a stock market server.
The problem is, after monitoring through WireShark, TCP window gets full, meaning that the receiving host (me) has trouble processing incoming data fast enough. 
I Know my data provider has disabled TCP acknowledgement from his side, so basically he just pushes TCP Packets and looks if they are "still there" : If he detects that they were not processed after a certain amount of time, connection is simply shut down.

I really don't know what to do, Ive disabled Windows 7's Auto Scale Tuning and also Heuristics, but that did not have any effect. I also noticed that there is no way to set TPC Windows Size (RWIN) on Windows 7.

I Know this is not a programming related question *per se* but it is somehow, because this is critical from the code point of view.

**EDIT**
A responder stated : "your application is not pulling data out of it fast enough"
This is fairly interesting, but I have no real idea on how to optimize this :

```
    private class IoContext
    {
        // The socket used for the operation:
        public Socket _ipcSocket;
        // The buffer used for the operation:
        public VfxMsgBlock _ipcBuffer;

        public IoContext(Socket socket, VfxMsgBlock buffer)
        {
            _ipcSocket = socket;
            _ipcBuffer = buffer;
        }
    }

    private void InitiateRecv(IoContext rxContext)
    {
        rxContext._ipcSocket.BeginReceive(rxContext._ipcBuffer.Buffer, rxContext._ipcBuffer.WrIndex,
            rxContext._ipcBuffer.Remaining(), 0, CompleteRecv, rxContext);
    }

    private void CompleteRecv(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        IoContext rxContext = ar.AsyncState as IoContext;
        if (rxContext != null)
        {
                int rxBytes = rxContext._ipcSocket.EndReceive(ar);
                if (rxBytes > 0)
                {
                    //Adjust the write index in the message block:
                    rxContext._ipcBuffer.WrIndex = rxContext._ipcBuffer.WrIndex + rxBytes;

                    //(...) Do Stuf here with data                        

                    rxContext._ipcBuffer.Crunch();

                    //Initiate another asynchronous read:
                    InitiateRecv(rxContext);
                }                
          }
     }
```

**EDIT 2** 
In response to Len Holgate :

I changed/checked the Recv Buffer size directly via c# property (got some troubles using GetSocketOption/SetSocketOption)

I can notice a slight performance change when I vary the Socket Buffer size, ie connection drops after 10mn with a big bufer (1000000) rather than 3mn (using 10240 or less (even 0, I don't know why... weird))

Here is the first WireShark log I am getting :

```
[SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1380 SACK_PERM=1 WS=128
```

It doesn't change whatever the Socket's receive buffer size

About Windows 7 & TCP Windows size, I meant than the re-write of TCP Management in Windows resulted in it being scaled automatically, and no registry parameter is available to set it "by hand". 
However, you are right : On a per-socket basis, it is adjustable using the receive buffer size.
Source [here](http://www.227volts.com/?p=802) among others

Comment: Can we see all of the connection handshake please.

Have you tried setting the Win 7 auto tuning back on ?

If you remove your 'business logic' and just pull data as fast as you can do you still fall behind?

What network utilisation are you seeing?

Does the wireshark log show a `zero window` just before disconnect?

Comment: can you show the entire block of code that includes you creating the socket, setting the options and then listening...

Answer (score 2):

If you disable ack processing in TCP, you're not talking TCP any more. You're using some wierd frankenprotocol which looks a bit like TCP.

Typically though you should use Windows TCP auto tuning - it is pretty good, although it does depend on the peer talking TCP (which in your case it isn't).

If you need to prevent the window from becoming full your best bet is to process data faster - chances are that the window is filling because your application is not pulling data out of it fast enough. Streamlining that should be your first port of call. Using async sockets is a good start, keeping multiple reads pending in a row so that the OS can hand the data off to your app as soon as it is ready would be another step in the right direction.

Finally, if you want to use UDP, you should probably try to use UDP instead of wierd TCP.

Comment: The problem is probably "//(...) Do Stuf here with data". If this takes too long, the receive window will fill while it is running. You should probably start the next read before you start processing the last one. Thats the main advantage of asynchronous reads.

Comment: True, multiple pending reads would be a good idea, but remember to deal with sequencing...

Comment: @Stewart : No... :-) I also thought that at first, so I just commented that part in my code and was still observing same behaviour (Besides, it just contained an async delegate). Would you please give me a hint on how to tweak my code to make multiple reads pending ? But I am a bit afraid that this would create a bottleneck too (ie, transposing the traffic Jam from the OS TCP Layer to the Application Layer). I would really be happy to find a way just to "read and process the quotes messages faster". I am using a powerful multicore and x64 but I can't seem to make it happen

Comment: @Stewart : PS : I did not express myself well : It is no Frankeprotocol, it's just a TCP_NODELAY from the server side (disabling Nagle)

Comment: Disabling nagle is probably the wrong thing to do. You want to keep your TCP frames full if you can, and nagle is the way to do that. That will help to keep things moving. The only reason to disable nagle is if you're sending very small messages and need low latency, in which case you might want to consider UDP anyway, or if you're hitting ack delays, in which case there are better ways to fix it. What kind of network are you running on?

Answer (score 2):

Have you set the socket's recv buffer to as large as you can?

See here for how to affect the TCP window size: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms819736.aspx

**Edited** to show what I get with two win 7 machines over a 1gb link, no changes to default settings, just setting `SO_RECVBUF` using `setsockopt()` on the listen socket, window size verified from the wireshark log of the connection... The actual window size is calculated from the advertised size and the multiplier that is implied by the scaling factor.

> ```
>  Set Recv  |Advertised |Scaling|Multiply| Actual TCP |Difference|
>    Buf to  |  Window   |       |  By    |Window size |          |
>    --------+-----------+-------+--------+----------- +----------+
>    default |   8192    |   8   |    256 |    2097152 |          | 
>       1024 |   1024    |   0   |      1 |       1024 |         0|
>      10240 |  10240    |   0   |      1 |      10240 |         0|
>   66666666 |  65535    |  10   |   1024 |   67107840 |   -441174|
>  666666666 |  65535    |  14   |  16384 | 1073725440 |-407058774|
> 1000000000 |  65535    |  14   |  16384 | 1073725440 | -73725440|
> 1073725440 |  65535    |  14   |  16384 | 1073725440 |         0|
> 1073741823 |  65535    |  14   |  16384 | 1073725440 |     16383|
> 1073741824 |   8192    |   8   |    256 |    2097152 |1071644672|
> 2147483647 |   8192    |   8   |    256 |    2097152 |2145386495|
> ```

So, clearly, it IS possible to affect the TCP Window size on a per socket basis on Windows 7. Could you provide a link to the document that makes you believe that *"As of windows 7 I just said that there is no TCP Window Size available for manual setting anymore (auto-tune netsh option only)"* please.

Note that the recv buf setting must be applied to the listening socket, or the outbound socket before you issue the connect as the window size scaling is transmitted in the opening handshake.

In all cases the call to `setsockopt()` succeeded and an immediate call to `getsockopt()` reported the recv buffer to be the size that was requested in the previous call to `setsockopt()`.

Note that although the theoretical maximum is the max value of an unsigned int, 2147483647, the actual maximum useful value appears to be 1073741823 (0x3FFFFFFF), this may vary with operating system version but bear in mind that an immediate call to `getsockopt()` returned the same value that had been set so it was impossible, except by looking at the wireshark log, to determine that values above 1073741823 were ignored entirely (at least from a window size perspective).

Of course this requires that the connecting peer is specifying a window scale option, even 0, to show that it accepts window scaling.

Please show us the wireshark connection log for the initial handshake packets. I can provide compiled code that you can you to test this is you want.

Comment: Yeah I tried moving it from 10240 to 40960 with no substantial effect. As of your link, I pointed out in my post that RWIN, ie TCP Window Size is not available for setting anymore on Windows 7

Comment: even a size of a Million did not do on buffer... :-/

Comment: When do you set it? On the listening socket? Do you call getsockopt after to check that it has been set? It certainly works for me on windows 7.

Comment: I checked while debugging that buffer size effectively changed. As of windows 7 I just said that there is no TCP Window Size available for manual setting anymore (auto-tune netsh option only)

Comment: Thank you for your very useful & inspiring edit. please see EDIT 2 on my Post.

Comment: @MikaJacobi You may have just said it but you were incorrect. Setting the socket receive buffer size determines the receive window.

Comment: The MSDN link doesn't lead anywhere and I couldn't easily find a comparable page. Is this information obsolete or is there a modern equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

As an addition the the already excellent answers I would suggest the following test: Pull data out as fast as you can and discard it immediately. This allows you to see if your processing speed really is the problem, or if it is somewhere else. You can't go faster that reading and throwing the data away.

Comment: Yes that was exactly the problem indeed. The processing was taking too long and socket data was stacking of in the buffer. I'll post and edit.