# Is the tcp window size relevant to the SND_BUF or RCV_BUF of the tcp socket?

Tags: tcp, setsockopt

I want to know when I change the SND_BUF of a socket via setsockopt API, will the original window size of the TCP layer be changed accordingly?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't change since it is *receive* window size, whereas `SO_SNDBUF` controls the size of the send buffer.

Comment: Then is the SO_RCVBUF relevant?

Comment: Yep, it needs to be set before calling `connect()` or `listen()` though.

Comment: See this answer for an example of how relevant. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8579250/7925